# adapter.getFilter().filter(newText); not triggered and not filtering anything

Tags: android, listview

The problem is when I change my simpleAdapter to CursorAdapter my SearchView doesn't work anymore. I am trying to debug using logcat but even in logcat no logs happen so I wondering why what's the problem of my code since the logcat doesn't show errors.

here is my codes

```
  SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search Title/Artist");

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {


            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

**Calling the CursorAdapter**

```
 Cursor res = db.query("songs",null,null,null,null,null,"title");


        adapter = new ClientCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this,res, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
////
////
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Calling the CursorAdapter and display it into my listview works well but when I'm trying to search in Searchview nothing happen, no changes happen to the listview.

one more thing.

I put the Toast inside the onQueryTextChange like this

```
@Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, newText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
```

The Toast displayed what I'd typing in Searchview. so I don't know what actually happen to my searchview. please help.